# Alternative to stream on a shared table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm building a continuous data pipeline using tasks and streams.  It works well for most of my solution, except when my source data is a database from a Snowflake share.

Although I can't explicitly find anything in Snowflake's documentation, I am assuming you cannot build a stream on a table based on a share, which makes sense based on my understanding of Snowflake's architecture.  When I tried to do it, I get the following error message:
*The table 'TABLE_A' was imported from a share and cannot be used.*

I would like to ask for suggestions on how I can identify changed records in my table other than the normal "full outer join" or "high water mark" solutions.  I'm hoping there is some creative way to use Snowflake features that will allow me to do this.

Performance is critical and there will be may table in the billions of rows.

Kind regards
Marius

Comment: I tried creating a materialized view on the share table, which is possible. And then a stream on the materialized view, which is not allowed. SQL compilation error: Object found is of type 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW', not specified type 'TABLE'.

Comment: I have not tested this yet, and whether you can leverage it depends on whether you can request this change on the PROVIDER side of the share.  But, have you tried having the PROVIDER enable `CHANGE_TRACKING` on the table that is being shared?  This would allow you to leverage the new `CHANGES` feature of Snowflake (maybe).  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html

Comment: Unfortunately CHANGE_TRACKING does not work on shares.  Good idea anyway.

Comment: Did you try it on the PROVIDER side table, rather than on the share?  It definitely won't work directly on the share.

Comment: Yes.  Tried it on the provider.  If you run SHOW TABLES on the consumer side, it even shows you that change tracking is enabled for the table.  But when you query it using CHANGES, it fails saying that time-travel is not available.

Comment: That's too bad.  I know there is a list of things that are being improved on both the STREAM/CHANGES side of things, as well as with SHARE, so hopefully these 2 things come together soon.